# Conditions for overdetermined system of homogeneous polynomials admit unique solution

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, multivariate-polynomial

I have a system of complex polynomials equal to zero with $n$ variables and each polynomials is homogeneous in degree. There are $m$ polynomials and $m>n$. So the system is overdetermined. Since all polynomials are homogeneous, I think zero is one of the solution of the system. But I don't know if there are more than one solutions. So I would like to ask what are the condition for such kind of system to admit unique solution?

So my question is, what are the conditions for a overdetermined system of homogeneous polynomials admit unique solution, which is zero?

Comment: If they're homogeneous polynomials with a common unique solution, it must be $(0,\cdots,0)$. Do you mean to be asking about the criteria for that, or are you after something else?

Comment: Here is a rather trivial collection of examples for $m=3$, $n=2$ that you can easily generalize to other values of $m,n$: $x^2+y^2=0$, $x^2+2y^2=0$, and any third homogeneous polynomial in two variables that you care to name.

Comment: @KReiser I am asking about the criteria for that.

Comment: @Ken.Wong You can [dehomogenize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_polynomial#Homogenization) the equations. Then the homogeneous system has only the trivial solution iff the dehomogenized system has no solutions. To check the latter use Groebner bases or resultants, see for example [Ways to show a system of polynomial equations has no solution](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181376/ways-to-show-a-system-of-polynomial-equations-has-no-solution) on MO.